# how to transfer information from first sub module to second?

Tags: java, git-submodules

I wanted to use area in the second sub module but I keep getting the error of "cannot find symbol" how can solve it?

Calculate the area of the room by using length and width (m)
Calculate the tins required to paint a room <-area

```
import java.util.*;
public class PaintRoom
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double areaRoom = calcRoomArea();
    int tinsRequired = calcTinsRequired();
    System.out.println("Total tins:" + tinsRequired);
}

public static double calcRoomArea()
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("==Length(m)==\nLength:");
    double length = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("==Width(m)==\nWidth:");
    double width = sc.nextDouble();
    double area = length*width;
    return area;

}

public static int calcTinsRequired()
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("==Paint Coverage(m)==\nPaint Coverage:");
    double paintCoverage = sc.nextDouble();
    int tinsRequired = (int)(area*paintCoverage);
    return tinsRequired;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you give us the full stack trace?

Comment: PaintRoom.java:28: error: cannot find symbol(area)     int tinsRequired =(int)(area*paintCoverage);

Answer (score 0):

In `calcTinsRequired()`, you never declare a variable named `area` but you use it when you're defining `tinsRequired`. I believe all you need to do to fix this is replace this line `int tinsRequired = (int)(area*paintCoverage);` with this `int tinsRequired = (int)(calcRoomArea()*paintCoverage);`. In addition, since you are casting to an int, you are potentially losing information because int is a 32-bit datatype, and double is a 64-bit datatype. You should cast to a long instead.

Comment: how can i declare area to clacTinsRequired? because when I change it to int tinsRequired = (int)(calcRoomArea()*paintCoverage); it requires me to insert length and width twice. sorry im new to programming =)

Comment: I didn't read your code fully. You use your original code, but add a method parameter to calcTinsRequired() and pass in area. E.G. make the method signature `public static int calcTinsRequired(double area)`. Also, if my answer answers your question, please upvote it and accept.

Comment: it gave me an error saying that method calcTinsRequired in class PaintRoom cannot be applied to given types;   int tinsRequired = calcTinsRequired();     required: double

Comment: You changed the method signature to require an argument, so pass in the argument

Comment: i dont really know how to change it to an argument ... sorry